# Chart for Saxophone finger notation in Musixtex with Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, musixtex

[image: Expected output: Saxophone finger chart]

I need to write some music chart for Saxophone. How to write the finger chart?
Thanks and regards

Comment: How do you write the rest? Many people here are profficient in TikZ but I don't even know where to begin with MusiXTeX. That said, I don't see any reference to PGF/TikZ in the MusiXtEX manual. Wouldn't it better to implement the notation with MusiXTeX directly (if possible) instead of adding TikZ to the mix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below you can find an starting code for Tikz.
Regards

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{float} %Paquete para posicionar Tablas
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}%Para signo igual
\usepackage{musicography}
\usepackage{musixtex} 
\input{musixlyr}
\input {musixcho}
\input {musixdat}%fecha
\input {musixfll}
\input {musixgre}%gregoriano
\input {musixper}%percusión
\input {musixppff}
\input {musixstr}
\input {musixvbm}  % experimental vectorized beams
\input {musixdbr} % lineas de barras punteadas, discontinuas y arbitrariamente discontinuas


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {
%Description of the Saxophone finger chart
\begin{music}
    \setclef1\treble % Clave de Sol para el Instrumento 1
    \nobarnumbers % Omite la numeración en los compases
    \nostartrule % Inicia sin barra vertical
    \startextract % Se inicia el fragmento musical
    %Primer compás
    \NOtes \sh{a} \wh a 
    \zcharnote{-11}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.2cm} La\musSharp{}}\en
    \NOtes \fl{b} \wh b 
    \zcharnote{-11}{\footnotesize \hspace*{-1.2cm} Si\musFlat{}}\en\setdoublebar
    \endextract % Se finaliza el fragmento musical
\end{music}   
};
\begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)}]
    %Código para grillas
  %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
  %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }
  
  %Código para dibujar el Saxophone
  %\draw [red,line width=2pt] (0.65,0.8) -- (0.65,0.1);
  %\draw [red,line width=2pt] (0.69,0.8) -- (0.69,0.1);
  \draw [red] (0.65,0.9) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.8) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.7) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.6) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.69,0.55) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.5) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.4) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.67,0.3) circle[radius=0.08cm];
  \draw [red,fill=red] (0.65,0.2) circle[radius=0.08cm];
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is as follow:

[image: output (feedback)]